# How to hide an activity from users?

Tags: android

How to create an activity that is hidden from users but available for admin? My app has an admin panel that should be hidden from users and is only available for admins. So, Is there a way I can implement it? Or I have to create different-different apps for users and admin ?

Comment: This nothing has to do with activity or android. your app needs a login screen that based on that input you authorize user privileges and enable/disable or hide/show the feature.

Comment: How would you find out that the user is an admin?

Comment: @abstractArrow What if my app doesn't need login activity?

Comment: If your application doesn't have online access 1) Two separate apps for admin and user 2) Login based on a device unique attribute, e.g. MAC Address.

Comment: You could add a hidden gesture recognizer or react to long-tap on a logo like [hide it pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hideitpro&hl=en) does. Or add an "admin login" menu in the settings of your app

Comment: @lucidbrot Thanks, Man. Great Idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,
if (KEY.equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_notification_parti).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_setting).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_edit_profile_particpant).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_payment).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_terms).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_send).setVisible(false);

            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_request_parti  ).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_training_parti  ).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_notification_parti  ).setVisible(false);
        }else if (KEY.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_see_all_connections ).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_active_courses ).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_taken_course ).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_mycoach ).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_edit_profile ).setVisible(false);
        }
```